# Removing values in an array that contain a specific number

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to remove any value that contains a `5` so in this case the `5`, `15`, `25` and `53` should all be removed.

Have tried the below and played around in irb but can't seem to get it to work

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 25, 53]
n.delete_if { |a| a =~ /5*/ }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for an [Array#`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
n.reject { |number| number.to_s =~ /5/ }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 2.4 comes with [`Integer#digits`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits):

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 25, 53]
n.reject { |i| i.digits.include? 5 }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) it works as well:

```
n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 25, 53]
n.delete_if { |a| a.to_s =~ /5/ }
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```